# Trying to add javascript using itext for displaying leading zeros. Affecting other fields

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, itext

I am trying to add javascript using iText to display leading zeros in PDF fields, which are otherwise not getting displayed. I mean, if I am adding '0044' into a field, its getting displayed as '44'.  So I added following Javascript using itext.

stamper.add("this.getField('TEST_FIELD').value = util.printf(\"%04d\",this.getField('TEST_FIELD').value)");

While that is working fine, it is affecting other fields in the PDF in a weird way. 
If any other numeric fields have values like $1.00, they are getting displayed as 1.

I am unable to figure it out in what way its affecting other fields.

Comment: Are you filling the form with iText? There is a method that allows you to define a value for the field (e.g. "44") as well as a display value (e.g. "0044"). Of course: the leading zeros disappear as soon as you click the field. It seems that you are adding JS that invalidates JS that is already present in your file, but it is hard to guess without having more info (which explains who nobody answers your question).

Comment: Thank you Lowagie. I was ovverriding existing Javascript while adding new one. And yes, I am using iText to fill the PDFs and merge them as well.

Comment: You say: I *was*. Does this mean you've now solved the problem? Or is the problem still unresolved?

Comment: The problem is solved.